# Laravel maintain a Session in subdomain of different server

Tags: session, laravel-4, cross-domain

Suppose in a domain (`app.domain.com`) I have set a Session like this:

```
Session::put('test', 'value');
```

Then in different domain (ex. `news.domain.com`) I want to retrieve that session value. Note that the other domain is located **ON DIFFERENT SERVER**, but still same domain name.

My question is, will `Session::get('test')` is available in `news.domain.com` if I set the laravel config file to `domain => '*.domain.com'`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have the subdomains hosted on different physical machines, setting the domain in `app/config/session.php` to this:

```
'domain' => '.domain.com'
```

will work as long as the two apps will be able to access a shared session data storage (for example using the `database` session driver and having a common database that stores the sessions).

Comment: and of course, they need to have the same app key right?

Comment: @Bogdan, you totally saved the day! I don't know if anyone else needs to know this, but the app/config/auth needs to be updated too. I had to change a web app from using the file session method to database. Could NOT figure out why they weren't looking at each other. Bah. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: What about those of us who redirect www.domain.com to domain.com? It is killing my sessions. E.g.  
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]