# How to maintain session with single laravel application over multiple domains

Tags: php, laravel, session, multiple-domains

Ex: I'm having main site say "main.com". Now I'm allowing users to add their custom domain so that they can access my site with their own custom domains. Now if they are loggedin in main.com, they should also remain as loggedin in their own custom domain.

Thanks

Comment: For sharing session across domains, you will have to write tricky session handlers, which involves but not limited to passing it as a get parameter.

Comment: @HirenGohel for example?

Comment: I just googling and found a link where they provide some workflow. Here it is: ` http://laravel.io/forum/03-14-2014-multiple-domains-how-to-share-login ` May be it helps you!

Comment: Visit this hope it will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463467/laravel-maintain-a-session-in-subdomain-of-different-server

Comment: Make a Route group on the custom domain like this: Route::group(['domain' => '{custom_domain}.{tld}'], function($domain) {
            Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'PageController@show', 'as' => 'page.customdomain']);
        });

Comment: Sorry didn't help. Anyways, thank you all for your help

Comment: @Siddharth: Please visit this: ` https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/share-session-from-multiple-domains-but-on-same-server `