# Share Laravel Session on Subdomains with different guards

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I'm currently using spatie/permissions and a Subclass of User with constraints to permissions to Login to subdomains in my application.

I now want to be able to share the session between my main domain `example.com` and the domains `some.example.com` where `some` is dynamically loaded from database.

When my logged-in User in example.com accesses the abc.example.com domain and is able to log in there I want to use the current session.

I use different guards on subdomain and domain with the SubUser and User classes as providers.

I already use the database session driver and can see in the logs that the same session id is loaded from database.
As the application is loading the same session from database I'm wondering why my user is not already logged in.

Anyone ever tried this and got a solution for this?

Comment: this might lead you somewhere: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/multi-domain-session

Comment: replied here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463467/laravel-maintain-a-session-in-subdomain-of-different-server

Comment: @Quezler looks similar to my issue. will try that. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I managed to resolve this issue.

My setup is all subdomains got the `user` guard and the main domain has the `admin` guard.

I realised that the `Auth::getName()` included the guard name and as I logged in using different guards I ended up having two active logins in one session. But these logins had different names and where only valid with the right guard. This guard being different in main domain and subdomains resulted in not really sharing login-state over domain and subdomains.

I managed to resolve this by overriding the default laravel `SessionGuard` and adding my own driver like so:

In `config/auth.php`:

```
'guards' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'extended_session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'extended_session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
]
```

In `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
\Auth::extend('extended_session', function ($app, $name, $config) {
    $providerConfig = $this->app['config']['auth.providers.'.$config['provider']];
    // If you don't use eloquent you need to alter the next line accordingly
    $provider = new EloquentUserProvider($app['hash'], $providerConfig['model']);
    return new SessionGuardExtended('extended_session', $provider, $this->app['session.store']);
});
```

And add a new Class named `SessionGuardExtended` like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard;
class SessionGuardExtended extends SessionGuard{}
```

This results in a shared session with the same auth name for domain and subdomains.

Comment: Thank you for this.
Laravel also uses the class' name:
```'login_'.$this->name.'_'.sha1(static::class)``` where `name` is the driver's name and static::class is in Oli's example `SessionGuardExtended` with the full namespace

Comment: This is the only solution I found to this problem and it works perfectly! Now, my admins have their sessions shared between the backoffice and the main domain but my users didn't get access to the backoffice. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Add `SESSION_DOMAIN` to your `.env` file and set it to `.example.com`

Comment: already did that. this resulted in laravel loading the same session id on `example.com` and `some.example.com` but still doesn't persist the logged in state

Comment: cleared out everything. cookies, session table, browser data, browser history, application cache...